# Converting a htaccess rewrite rule to nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, rewrite

this is my first posting here, if i missed something please be indulge.

I have got a htaccess rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^soap=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?index\.php$ http://backendserver.com  /index.php?soap=%1 [L,R=302]
```

The requests:

```
http://frontend.com/?soap=123 
http://frontend.com/index.php?soap=123
```

are both redirecting me to the Backend-Server. So far so good.

Now im trying to move from apache2 to nginx.

```
location / {
if ($args ~ "^soap=([^&]+)"){
   #return 404;
   rewrite ^/?index\.php$ http://www.zam24.de/index.php?soap=%1 redirect;
}
```

Now i got 2 Problems that i can not handle alone:

1. I dont get redirected, but if replace the "rewrite..." with "return 404;" 
   i get a 404.
2. If I request index.php?soap=123 and not just ?soap=123 it will ignore the rewrite rule and "execute" the index.php

My full nginx-config can be found on: http://pastebin.com/ULRyNeZ4

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you're new to Nginx you should read "If is Evil". Note that it is sometimes necessary to use "if", and it does work fine if you understand it https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this configuration:

```
location / {
    if ($arg_soap) {
         rewrite ^ http://www.zam24.de/index.php?soap=$arg_soap redirect;
    }
}
```

We test here for the `soap` argument in the query string. If it is found, we rewrite the URL to the destination and pass the `soap` argument to the rewrite destination.

We don't need to use regex matching / capturing, since nginx already has query string arguments available in variables.